# Fatal error, relating to namespace in php

Tags: php, namespaces, fatal-error, traits

I am wandering why this below code gives an error:

```
<?php 

namespace Notebook\Routers{

    function exploder($request_uri){
        $explode = explode("/", $request_uri); 
        return ["count"=> count($explode), "values"=>$explode]; 
    }
}

namespace{
use Notebook\Routers; 
exploder($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
}
```

It says `Fatal error: Call to undefined function exploder() in /var/www/index.php on line 13`

Unless there is something I am missing. The `use Notebook\Routers` should be able to import the function in the current namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Just look documentation about [aliasing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) and call your function like this:

```
Routers\exploder($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Comment: Well, ay what point does one use the use keyword then. I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The 'use' keyword allows you to alias other namespaces within your current namespace. Here you have included a global namespace and the specific class you wanted to use, Routers.  To get your code to work, explicitly call out the namespace as I have done below,

```
namespace Notebook\Routers{

    function exploder($request_uri){
        $explode = explode("/", $request_uri); 
        return ["count"=> count($explode), "values"=>$explode]; 
    }
}

namespace Notebook\Routers{ 
    exploder($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
}
```

or, you can use the previous answer's suggestion and use the function

```
Routers\exploder($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])";
```

When you used the 'use' command for the namespace Notebook\Routers, that namespace was implicitly aliased to Routers.  As you are not working with multiple namespaces in the same file, I don't believe using the 'use' keyword is necessary.